# Version function does not work for JS files in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I wrote the following code that combined CSS and JS files with the Webpack.mix.js and the correct result, but the version function does not work for the JS file! What can I do to get it right, and both CSS and JS become version?

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.setPublicPath('/')
    .copy('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js', 'resources/js')
    .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'resources/js')
    .scripts([
        'resources/js/bootstrap.js',
        'resources/js/jquery.js'
    ], 'resources/js/app.js');

mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles([
        'public/css/app.css',
        'public/css/myCss.css'
    ], 'public/css/all.css')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .version();
```

**mix-manifest.json**

```
{
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=35978cdc6a38f7d64fbb",
    "/css/all.css": "/css/all.css?id=eda19119aa76ef087fde"
}
```

i added `<script src="{{ mix('js/all.js') }}"></script>` into my Blade file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, build your webpack.mix.js configuration like so.

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles([
        'public/css/myCss.css'
    ], 'public/css/all.css')
    .version();
```

Make sure jQuery and Bootstrap are installed. You also may want to update Laravel Mix to the latest.

```
npm install bootstrap
npm install jquery
npm install laravel-mix
```

In /resources/js/bootstrap.js at the top, add or modify these lines. This loads jQuery and Bootstrap in your application.

```js
window._ = require('lodash');

try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

In /resources/sass/app.scss:

```
@import 'variables';

// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Compile your assets.

```
npm run production
```

You now have two CSS file references, both at the top of your template Blade file.

```js
<script src="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ mix('css/all.css') }}"></script>
```

At the bottom of the template, use `app.js`:

```js
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Take note that your mix-manifest file now has this content.

```js
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=0b5e26cf3116bf443cac",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=a99cdff2ed9d413fcb8a",
    "/css/all.css": "/css/all.css?id=a99cdff2ed9d413fcb8a"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I trying to do your solution but my mix-manifest file not like the content of your file!!! mix-manifest: ```{
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=35978cdc6a38f7d64fbb",
    "/css/all.css": "/css/all.css?id=eda19119aa76ef087fde"
} ```

Comment: Do the version numbers change every time you run 'npm run prod'? If not, that's not the correct mix-manifest file.

Comment: You said right. when I remove ```mix.setPublicPath('/')
    .copy('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js', 'resources/js')
    .copy('node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js', 'resources/js')
    .scripts([
        'resources/js/bootstrap.js',
        'resources/js/jquery.js'
    ], 'resources/js/app.js'); ``` from webpack.mix.js thats work correct. Why is this happening?

Comment: Since you have a slash at the end of mix.setPublicPath() your mix-manifest file should be in the root of the project, instead of inside the public folder (/public). You are overwriting the default behavior.

Comment: @Bahar I updated the instructions with the proper way to do it.

Comment: I understood your solution. But I have a question how to copy Bootstrap and Jquery files or any other files from node_modules in resources/js so that I do not have this problem?

Comment: In /resources/js/bootstrap.js is where you load Bootstrap and jQuery and any other JS libraries. The libraries will be combined and added to /public/js/app.js. CSS/SCSS gets loaded in /resources/sass/app.scss. These libraries will be combined in /public/csss/app.css.

Comment: So, can it be concluded that if the copy function is used, the version function does not work?!

Comment: No, it worked fine for me. However, you do not need to copy jQuery and Bootstrap from the /node_modules directory. You only need to copy CUSTOM js and CSS. Either way, versions work fine.

Comment: Forgive me for taking your time. Yes, I do not need to copy Bootstrap and jQuery, but why does the version function not work correctly for me?

Comment: That's because you are doing two Laravel Mix instances. The first one does not have .version() in it.

Comment: Thank you very much